# Getting database names from server

Tags: node.js, ravendb

I want to do a simple thing: get the database names on a RavenDB server. Looks straightforward according to the docs (https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.1/csharp/client-api/operations/server-wide/get-database-names), however I'm facing a chicken-and-egg problem.

The problem comes because I want to get the database names without knowing them in advance. The code in the docs works great, but requires to have an active connection to a DocumentStore. And to get an active connection to a DocumentStore, is mandatory to select a valid database. Otherwise I can't execute the GetDatabaseNamesOperation.

That makes me think that I'm missing something. Is there any way to get the database names without having to know at least one of them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The database isn't mandatory to open a store. Following code works with no problems:

```
using (var store = new DocumentStore
            {
                Urls = new[] { "http://live-test.ravendb.net" }
            })
            {
                store.Initialize();
                var dbs = store.Maintenance.Server.Send(new GetDatabaseNamesOperation(0, 25));
            }
```

We send GetDatabaseNamesOperation to the ServerStore, which is common for all databases and holds common data (like database names).

Comment: Ok, I finally got my error. I don't know if I misread it or if they updated the docs. I wasn't calling store.Maintenance.Server.Send. I was calling store.Maintenance.Send. It works in exactly the same way... except it requires to have a database name to operate. In my defense I will say that the docs don't tell the difference between the two apart of a vague 'Maintenance.server.send is for administrative tasks'. But administrative tasks work as well on Maintenance.Send.